# Implementation of IdentityUserLogin<TKey>

Tags: c#, identityserver4, .net-core-3.1

I have to migrate my IDS4 Project from .net Framework 4.6.1 to .net Core3.1.1

I have struck at the following:

```
var userLogins = await context.Set<IdentityUserLogin>().Where(x => x.UserId == user.Id)       .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I'm getting this error:

> Using the generic type 'IdentityUserLogin' requires 1 type
>   arguments.

Answer (score 0):

This means that you need to provide a generic type parameter.

These are provided directly after the type name in angle brackets. For example: `IdentityUserLogin<string>`.

More info: 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/generics/generic-type-parameters